# Populate a new column in dataframe, based on values in differently indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, each with a different index, and I'd like to merge the 'hop' column from **df2** into **df1** based on the 'src' column in df1 and the index in df2.

```
df1
     src    dest    val
  0    1       2      X
  1    1       2      Y
  2    1       3      Z
  3    1       4      X
  4    2       2      X
  5    3       2      Y
  6    4       3      Z
  7    4       1      X

df1
 id  hop   
  1    3
  2    5
  3    2
  4    3
```

i.e. the resulting dataframe needs to be merged as such:

```
df3
     src    dest    val    hop
  0    1       2      X      3
  1    1       2      Y      3 
  2    1       3      Z      3
  3    1       4      X      3
  4    2       2      X      5
  5    3       2      Y      2
  6    4       3      Z      3
  7    4       1      X      3
```

I think it's probably a pd.merge() or pd.join() operation but I'm having a spot of bother with it :(

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,left_on='src',right_on='id')
`

Comment: @Wen, noted on the dup issue, I'll refrain myself :)

Comment: @sacul Thank you man :-)

Comment: @Wen thanks for flagging the duplicate, duly noted!